# Do the leaves of Yggdrasil (the World Tree) have any special properties?

Tags: norse, yggdrasil

Do the leaves of the World Tree (Yggdrasil) have any special properties in Norse Mythology?

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34834/do-the-leaves-of-yggdrasil-the-world-tree-have-any-special-properties

Comment: I receive many questions like this mostly from Dragon Quest players, a game in which the leaves of the World Tree revives a dead member of the party to full HP...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if the leaves had any magical properties, but apparently it dripped honey:

I know an ash-tree stands called Yggdrasill,
a high tree, soaked with shining loam;
from there come the dews which fall in the valley,
ever green, it stands over the well of fate. ([Vsp](http://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/poe/poe03.htm). 19, Larrington)

The dew that falls from it on to the earth, this is what people call honeydew, and from this bees feed. (Snorri/Faulkes, [Gylf](http://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/pre/pre04.htm) 17)

(The translations are by Carolyne Larrington and Anthony Faulkes.)

Ash trees exude a sticky sap called manna or honeydew, which runs from the [branches and leaves](https://earthandstarryheaven.com/2015/04/07/honey-ash/). Apart from bees, the [goat Heidrun](http://www.godchecker.com/pantheon/norse-mythology.php?deity=HEIDRUN) ate this honey, which probably was transformed into the mead that ran from her udders.